# Objective C - JSON to CoreData with category relation

Tags: objective-c, json, core-data, nsdictionary

I'm trying to save a JSON result to core data.
I'm struggling with all sorts of array & dictionary hacks but there must be a better way or 'best practice' to achieve this. It seems pretty straight forward.

**JSON**

```
{
"Specifications" : [

{
  "Name" : "specification 1",
  "ID" : "123",
  "SpecificationsCategory" : {
    "Name" : "category 1",
    "ID" : "999"
  },
},

{
  "Name" : "specification 2",
  "ID" : "1234",
  "TechSpecCategory" : {
    "Name" : "category 1",
    "ID" : "999"
  },
},

{
  "Name" : "specification 3",
  "ID" : "12345",
  "TechSpecCategory" : {
    "Name" : "category 2",
    "ID" : "444"
  }      
},

{
  "Name" : "specification 4",
  "ID" : "123456",
  "TechSpecCategory" : {
    "Name" : "category 2",
    "ID" : "444"
  },
},

{
  "Name" : "specification 5",
  "ID" : "1234567",
  "TechSpecCategory" : {
    "Name" : "category 2",
    "ID" : "444"
  },
},

]}
```

**Core Data Model** I can change this if necessary.

[image: Core Database Model]
How can I create the relation where the "TechSpecCategory" must be unique in the core data but isn't defined as unique in the received JSON.

- Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369079/how-can-i-save-json-objects-to-core-data Try this link

Comment: I don't see how that question explains how I can make the relation between a unique category..